# Laravel-mix with gulp extension

Tags: laravel, gulp, laravel-mix

We are upgrading an application from an self made MVC to laravel. In that project we were using Gulp for the js files. in gulp we used an extension called 'gulp-js-import'. We used it like this in the gulpfile.js

```
//
var jsImport = require('gulp-js-import');

gulp.task('js', function() {

   return gulp.src('./js/script.js')
        .pipe(jsImport({hideConsole: true})) <-- notice jsImport
        .pipe(concat('script.min.js'))
        // .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));    
});
```

so we could use the @import function in the js/script.js file like this:

```
//
@import "../lib/jquery-2.2.0.min.js";
@import "../lib/jquery/easing.min.js";
@import "../lib/wnumb/wnumb.js";
//
```

So now i am trying to do that in laravel mix but I cant really find anything about this in the docs from laravel mix, maybe I overlooked it?

I know there are many ways to do this in the new EC6 but right now that is not an option. We can discuss this for a very long time but for now please work with me what I have now.

So right now in the laravel app in the 'webpack.mix.js' I have this:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js')
    .less('resources/less/_style.less', 'public/css');
```

From here I have no idea where to start cause I cant find anything about it. Or is it better to install gulp and use that for the time being?

EDIT:
If am asking something very stupid then please just tell that. As far as I know laravel-mix is gulp, right?

Comment: Laravel mix will compile your ES6 to regular JavaScript to have full support with browsers, so you can use `import`. Laravel mix is webpack.

Comment: I think you have not read everything on my topic. as stated 'I know there are many ways to do this in the new EC6 but right now that is not an option. We can discuss this for a very long time but for now please work with me what I have now.' <--

Comment: Ok, so you have a `resources/js/app.js` file in which you would want to load some other files? Are they node_modules or custom libraries?

Comment: extract the plugin code jsImport into a standalone module and use it in laravel-mix. maybe tedious but soves the problem

Comment: Gulp is not really compatible with mix (mix uses webpack) so unless you're willing to translate your existing code to something that can work with mix you're probably stuck with using gulp for now. Using gulp is fine by the way just because you migrated to laravel doesn't mean you must use `mix`.

Comment: thanks guys for the responses, i have installed gulp and use it that way. In the future we will refactor it to EC6.